# How render dynamics templates?

Tags: render, crystal-lang

I try render template from variable, but is not works.

```
require "kilt/slang"

path_to_file = "/home/sample.slang"
Kilt.render(path_to_file)
```

And i have next error:

```
in example.cr:4: undefined macro method 'Var#split'
Kilt.render(path_to_file)
```

Comment: It can't it has to be hard coded paths.  I guess you could make every template into a method and switch statement to call it or something?  I've "heard of" dynamic templates for crystal but never used one..

Answer (score 1):

`Kilt` renders templates at compile-time, so the template name needs to be known at compile time. If that is the case, you can go ahead as [Sergey Fedorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1597964/sergey-fedorov) suggested. `Kilt.render` is a macro and thus it's argument needs to be a literal, but literals can be produced by a macro.

If the value of `path_to_file` is not known at compile time, this won't work with `Kilt`. In that case you'd either consider a redesign of your implementation (maybe you can do this some other way) or use a compile-time template engine. I can recommend [crinja](https://github.com/straight-shoota/crinja) for this (I'm the author of that shard). An alternative is [liquid.cr](https://github.com/TechMagister/liquid.cr), which should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Sergey!

Kilt renders the template at compile time and you variable `path_to_file` at current moment not resolved yet. Instead variable you can use the constant, it accessible for macro:

```
PATH_TO_FILE = "/home/sample.slang"
Kilt.render(PATH_TO_FILE)
```

or wrap in a macro:

```
path_to_template = "sample.slang"

macro render_file(path)
  Kilt.render(path)
end

puts render_file(path_to_template)
```

Comment: It didn't work to, error through constant: `undefined macro method 'Path#split'`
error through macro: `undefined macro method 'Call#split'`. Maybe i can read file and compile string `Kilt.some_process(File.read(file_path))` ?

Comment: You would need to use `Kilt.render({{ PATH_TO_FILE }})`.

Comment: The `render_file(path_to_template)` example won't work for the same reason as `Kilt.render(path_to_template)` doesn't work: They're macros and can't receive the value of local variables.